# C++ Qt easy way of making Incremental PushButtons?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been using Qt to make somewhat of Civ5 style game. I've just started using Qt and i am probably writing my code very inefficiently so sorry about my code.

```
if(buildings[0][0][0])
ui->r_1_n_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_camp_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_camp_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_camp_pressed+";}");
else if(buildings[0][0][1])
ui->r_1_n_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_fort_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_fort_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_fort_pressed+";}");
else
ui->r_1_n_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_pressed+";}");

if(buildings[0][1][0])
ui->r_1_n_2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_camp_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_camp_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_camp_pressed+";}");
else if(buildings[0][1][1])
ui->r_1_n_2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_fort_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_fort_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_fort_pressed+";}");
else
ui->r_1_n_2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_pressed+";}");

if(buildings[0][2][0])
ui->r_1_n_3->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_camp_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_camp_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_camp_pressed+";}");
else if(buildings[0][2][1])
ui->r_1_n_3->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_fort_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_fort_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_fort_pressed+";}");
else
ui->r_1_n_3->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_pressed+";}");

if(buildings[0][3][0])
ui->r_1_n_4->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_camp_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_camp_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_camp_pressed+";}");
else if(buildings[0][3][1])
ui->r_1_n_4->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_fort_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_fort_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_fort_pressed+";}");
else
ui->r_1_n_4->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_pressed+";}");

if(buildings[0][4][0])
ui->r_1_n_5->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_camp_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_camp_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_camp_pressed+";}");
else if(buildings[0][4][1])
ui->r_1_n_5->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_fort_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_fort_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_fort_pressed+";}");
else
ui->r_1_n_5->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_pressed+";}");
```

i would like to know because i have about 50 other PushButtons name , r_1_n_(i), because all of the statements are similar is their any way to implement some time of for loop which decreases the amount of code needed. so im thinking of something like

```
    for(int j = 0; j < number; i++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        if(buildings[j][i][0])
            ui->r_(j)_n_(i)->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url"+url_camp_inactive+";} QPushButton:hover { border-image: url"+url_camp_active+";} QPushButton:focus {border-image: url"+url_camp_pressed+";}");     
    }
}
```

now obviously doing r_(j)*n*(i) doesn't work but i was wondering if there was a way to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: You can store pointers to the buttons in a two dimensional vector/list as well and access them like your `buildings` vector/list

Comment: Thanks! i shall try this.

Comment: You might also use a macro, as it can perform the `i` and `j` substitutions from your pseudocode. However, macros are sometimes frowned upon and using the C++ language to accomplish your goal is the preferred solution.

Comment: Every one of these objects has a name, and you can look them up **programmatically** by name using `findChildren`. The object name is the variable name, they are one and the same.